# Random Algorithm for calculating expectaiotn

Tags: algorithms, expected-value

I am asked to devise a random algorithm for the next question:
Input: a list of n real numbers $\in [0,1], \epsilon>0, \delta>0$.
Output: a real number t.
Requierment: For each input, $|\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_n}{n}-t|<\epsilon$ with probability at least $1-\delta$.

I have tried to use Chernoff inequality and got some unuseable answer- $\frac{2\epsilon^2}{ln(\frac{2}{\delta})}>k$
which means that if I take less elements I get closer to the mean.
Even worse, for little $\epsilon$'s I get a number less than 1 which make no sense at all.

I would very appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This, like the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094904/probabilistic-algorithm-for-the-weak-law-of-large-numbers-wlln) asks for a randomized algorithm.  What's random here is not the $a_i$ numbers but the random subset $S$ described below.

For a value of $m$ to be determined later, which will depend on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ but not $n$, pick a random subset $S\subseteq[n]$ of size $m$, and let $x$ be the average of the $a_i$ such that $i\in S$.

It is easy to see that the expectation of $x$ is $\mu$ and the variance of $x$ goes like $2/m$.  (Write $x=\sum_{i\in S} a_i / m = \sum_{i=1}^n I_i a_i / m$ where $I_i$ is the indicator of the event that $i\in S$.  (Note that $P(\sum_{i=1}^n I_i=m)=1$ so the $I_i$ are not independent.) Check that $$EI_i = \frac m n,$$ $$\text{Var}(I_i) = \frac mn(1-\frac mn),$$ $$\text{Cov}(I_i,I_j) = \frac m n \frac{m-n}{n(n-1)}\text{ if } i\ne j$$ and so on.)

Now use Chebyshev's inequality: for given $\epsilon$ you can choose $m$ so big (independent of $n$) that the $\delta$ condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks,
are you sure? why would $I_i,I_j$ be dependent? They are the indicators of independent $a_i$'s.

Comment: You misunderstand.  I have edited my post to try to make this clearer.  The $I_i$ describe the random set $S$, not anything about the $a_i$.  In particular, they are not "indicators of independent $a_i$'s''.